# Using computed min/max image values to set min/max visualization parameters in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to use the calculated min/max values of an image region to set the min/max visualization parameters of that image.  I can retrieve the actual numbers, but can't use them as variables in the visualization parameters block.  I keep getting the error:

> Shaded: Layer error: Can't encode object: abs()
>  Computes the
>   absolute value of the input.
>  Args: this:input (Number): The
>   input value.

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/States')
    .filter(ee.Filter.and(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Utah')));

var DEM = ee.Image('USGS/NED').clip(fc);
var Terrain = ee.Terrain.products(DEM).select('slope');
print(Terrain);

var visPct = Terrain.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([5,95]).setOutputs(['min','max']),
    geometry: fc,
    scale: 10, 
    bestEffort: true
  });

var Min = visPct.getNumber('slope_min');
var Max = visPct.getNumber('slope_max');
print(Min,Max);

var vizParams = {
  min: Min, 
  max: Max, 
  palette: ['blue','green','Yellow','red']
};

Map.centerObject(fc);
Map.addLayer(Terrain, vizParams, 'Shaded');
```

The only thing that I can figure out is that GEE is trying to display the image before the min/max values are calculated.

Comment: Use `getInfo()` or `evaluate()`. Make sure to read [serverVSclient](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Map.addLayer()` visualization parameters are expected to be client-side JS objects, but you are providing server-side EE objects (`ee.Number`). Use the `.evaluate()` function to convert server-side objects to client-side objects.

Here, I've included the computed min and max values in an `ee.Dictionary` object and applied the `.evaluate()` function to it. A client-side dictionary object (`dict`) is made available within the scope of the anonymous function, where the min and max values can then be referenced and set as visualization parameters for displaying the image to the Map.

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/63982e36413ee00282c2b32b254515a4)

```js
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/States')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Utah'));

var DEM = ee.Image('USGS/NED').clip(fc);
var Terrain = ee.Terrain.products(DEM).select('slope');
print(Terrain);

var visPct = Terrain.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.percentile([5,95]).setOutputs(['min','max']),
  geometry: fc,
  scale: 10, 
  bestEffort: true
});

// #########################################################
// ### ▼ EDITED ▼ ###
// #########################################################

var minMax = ee.Dictionary({
  minVal: visPct.getNumber('slope_min'),
  maxVal: visPct.getNumber('slope_max')
});

print(minMax);

minMax.evaluate(function(dict) {
  var vizParams = {
    min: dict.minVal, 
    max: dict.maxVal, 
    palette: ['blue','green','Yellow','red']
  };

  Map.centerObject(fc);
  Map.addLayer(Terrain, vizParams, 'Shaded');
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked perfectly.  I still need to figure out the server/client side shift.